# How do I reshape only parts of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         Date       City_State  HousingPrice      DowPrice    NasqPrice
0     1996-04     New York, NY      169300.0   5579.864351  1135.628092
1     1996-04  Los Angeles, CA      157700.0   5579.864351  1135.628092
2     1996-04      Houston, TX       86500.0   5579.864351  1135.628092
3     1996-04      Chicago, IL      114000.0   5579.864351  1135.628092
4     1996-04      Phoenix, AZ       88100.0   5579.864351  1135.628092
5     1996-05     New York, NY      169800.0   5616.707742  1220.540472
6     1996-05  Los Angeles, CA      157600.0   5616.707742  1220.540472
```

I'm trying to reshape the dataframe so that I could plot it.
Is there a simple way to move the DowPrice and NasqPrice into the City_State column so it looks something like this, without having to split the dataframe in two, reshape them and then merge them back?

```
         Date       Category        Price        
0     1996-04     New York, NY      169300.0   
1     1996-04  Los Angeles, CA      157700.0   
2     1996-04      Houston, TX      86500.0   
3     1996-04      DowPrice         5579.864351   
4     1996-04      NasqPrice        1135.628092
```

Comment: I can think of other ways to do it, but not simpler.

Comment: Presume you have other values of `Date`, can you add other values to your example? Do you have the full set of each `Price` on each `Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df=pd.concat([
    df.groupby("Date")["DowPrice"].first().to_frame().rename(
        columns={"DowPrice": "Price"}
    ).assign(Category="Dow"), 
    df.groupby("Date")["NasqPrice"].first().to_frame().rename(
        columns={"NasqPrice": "Price"}
    ).assign(Category="Nasdaq"), 
    df.set_index("Date").rename(
        columns={"City_State": "Category", "HousingPrice": "Price"}
    ).drop(["NasqPrice", "DowPrice"], axis=1)
], axis=0, sort=False).reset_index()
```

Output (I removed spaces in categories on purpose - just as a shortcut to get data from your df - you will see them fine, while using the code above):

```py
       Date        Price       Category
0   1996-04  5579.864351            Dow
1   1996-05  5616.707742            Dow
2   1996-04  1135.628092         Nasdaq
3   1996-05  1220.540472         Nasdaq
4   1996-04     169300.0     NewYork,NY
5   1996-04     157700.0  LosAngeles,CA
6   1996-04      86500.0     Houston,TX
7   1996-04     114000.0     Chicago,IL
8   1996-04      88100.0     Phoenix,AZ
9   1996-05     169800.0     NewYork,NY
10  1996-05     157600.0  LosAngeles,CA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reshape/melt` to do whatever you want, but your intent is not totally clear.

You want `Price` to denote:

- `HousingPrice` for each `(City_State, Date)`, if `Category` was a `City_State`
- else `DowPrice`/`NasqPrice` for that `Date`

So you want to `reshape/melt` multiple columns, selecting depending on the value of `Category`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and append it to itself, although I guess I'm reshaping and merging...

```
df.append(
df[['Date', 'DowPrice', 'NasqPrice']].drop_duplicates()\
                                     .melt('Date')\
                                     .rename(columns= {'variable':'City_State','value':'HousingPrice'})
).drop(columns = ['DowPrice','NasqPrice'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are asking for.

If you are looking to read the data from a csv:

```
import csv as cs

with open('/Documents/prices.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader=cs.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
       print(','.join(row))
```

This is the easiest I could find if you export the data as a csv file with pandas dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Documents/prices.csv')
part1 = data.filter(items = ['Date', 'Category', 'HousingPrice'])
```

However, it seems like you might want to be able to plot the date of the housing price over the dates of the dowjowns price over the nasqPirce. I would just split up the dataframe into 3 series then plot that.

Where the three series are:

```
part1 = data.filter(items = ['Date', 'Category', 'HousingPrice'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data.filter(items = ['Date', 'NasqPrice']))
d3 = pd.DataFrame(data.filter(items = ['Date', 'DowPrice']))
```

Or just simply: (this may be wrong and need an edit)

```
lines = data.plot.line(x='date', y=['HousingPrice', 'DowPrice', 'NasqPrice'])
```